# Using AWK to sort lines and columns together

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I'm doing an assignment where I've been asked to find files between a certain size and sha1sum them.  I've specifically been asked to provide the output in the following format:

Filename Sha1 File Size

all on one line.  I'm not able to create additional files.

I've tried the following:

```
for listed in $(find /my/output -type f -size -20000c):
do
sha1sum "$listed" | awk '{print $1}'
ls -l "$listed" | awk '{print $9 $5}'
done
```

which gives me the required output fields, but not in the requested format, i.e.

```
sha1sum
filename filesize
```

Could anyone suggest a manner in which I'd be able to get all of this on a single line?

Thank you :)

Comment: Didn't test but would changing the first call to awk to `awk '{printf "%s", $1}'` suffice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the `stat` command to avoid needing to parse the output of `ls`, you can simply echo all the values you need:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' listed
do
  echo "$listed" $(sha1sum "$listed") $(stat -c "%s" "$listed")
done < <(find /my/output -type f -size -20000c -print0)
```

Check your version of `stat`, though, the above is GNU. On OS X, e.g., would be

```
stat -f "%z" $listed
```

Comment: This works beautifully, I had considered stat but couldn't get the correct operators . Thank you.

Comment: 1) [Don't use find with a for loop](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) Use a `while` loop and set `find` to `print0` or this loop will break with file names with spaces. 2) Add `"$listed"` (ie, quote the file names) -- same reason. Downvoting only until you fix that error... Otherwise, great answer.

Comment: Thanks for the improvements, @dawg. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

With single pipeline:

```
find /my/path-type f -size -20000c -printf "%s " -exec sha1sum {} \; | awk '{ print $3,$2,$1 }'
```

An exemplary output (as a result of my local test) in the needed format `FILENAME SHA1 FILESIZE`:

```
./GSE11111/GSE11111_RAW.tar 9ed615fcbcb0b771fcba1f2d2e0aef6d3f0f8a11 25446400
./artwork_tmp 3a43f1be6648cde0b30fecabc3fa795a6ae6d30a 40010166
```

Comment: This also works beautifully, thank you.  I can only mark one question as correct, and I went with the one above as I was still able to use a 'for' loop.

Comment: @RickStein: [Please read](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) why this is the correct answer currently. You should either call the processes with an `-exec` from `find` or use a `while` loop and `-print0` to read files from `find`. Using a `for` loop to do that is a potential bad error.